# Count the number of times a letter appears in a text file in python

Tags: python

I'm aiming to create a `python` script that counts the number of times each letter appears from a text file. So if the text file contained `Hi there`, the output would be something like

```
E is shown 2 times
H is shown 2 times
I is shown 1 time
R is shown 1 time
T is shown 1 time
```

I've tried different ways of getting this but I have no output being shown as I carry on getting syntax errors. I've tried the following

```
import collections
import string

def count_letters(example.txt, case_sensitive=False):
    with open(example.txt, 'r') as f:
        original_text = f.read()
    if case_sensitive:
        alphabet = string.ascii_letters
        text = original_text
    else:
        alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
        text = original_text.lower()
    alphabet_set = set(alphabet)
        counts = collections.Counter(c for c in text if c in alphabet_set)

    for letter in alphabet:

        print(letter, counts[letter])
    print("total:", sum(counts.values()))

    return counts
```

And

```
def count_letters(example.txt, case_sensitive=False):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
    with open(example.txt, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    if not case_sensitive:
        alpahbet = alphabet[:26]
        text = text.lower()
        letter_count = {ltr: 0 for ltr in alphabet}
    for char in text:
        if char in alphabet:
            letter_count[char] += 1
    for key in sorted(letter_count):
        print(key, letter_count[key])
    print("total", sum(letter_count()))
```

Comment: I think you have an indentation problem with the **count** assignation.

Comment: @vmonteco on which script?

Comment: what is the syntax error it shows?

Comment: @smitthy The first one

Comment: The edit view shows a lot of tabs-vs-spaces weirdness in your posted code. Check to see if any of that exists in the original code.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel With the first one, I get `multiple statements found while compiling a single statement` on the first line and in the second one, I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for the dot where it's `example.txt`

Comment: `example.txt` is not a valid parameter name.

Comment: I've also tried both with the `'example.txt` but with the first one, I still get `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement` after the first line. And with the second one, I get `invalid syntax` when it highlights the second `'` on `'example.txt'` on the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems I found when running your script. One was correctly found by @Priyansh Goel in his answer: you can't use `example.txt` as a parameter. You should just choose a variable name like `text_file` and when you call the function, you pass in the string of the file's name.

Also there was an indentation error or two. Here's the script I got to work:

```
import collections
import string

def count_letters(text_file, case_sensitive=False):
    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
        original_text = f.read()
    if case_sensitive:
        alphabet = string.ascii_letters
        text = original_text
    else:
        alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
        text = original_text.lower()
        alphabet_set = set(alphabet)
        counts = collections.Counter(c for c in text if c in alphabet_set)

    for letter in alphabet:
        print(letter, counts[letter])

    print("total:", sum(counts.values()))

    return counts

count_letters("example.txt")
```

If you will only ever use this on `"example.txt"`, just get rid of the first parameter and hard code the file name into the function:

```
def count_letters(case_sensitive=False):
    with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
        ...

count_letters()
```

One of the best skills you can develop as a programmer is learning to read and understand the errors that get thrown. They're not meant to be scary or frustrating (although sometimes they are), they're meant to be helpful. Syntax errors like what you had are especially useful. If it isn't totally obvious what the errors are indicating, copy and paste the error into a Google search and more often than not you'll find the answer to your question already exists out there.

Good luck in learning! Python was a great choice for your (presumably) first language!

Comment: `example.txt` is the file that's containing `Hi there`

Comment: It doesn't matter what the file contains, but the fact that you're trying to use `example.txt` as a parameter is what's wrong. If you're only ever going to use that one text file, and never will want to run your function on another text file, just leave it out of the parameters to the function and reference the string `"example.txt"` in your `with open...` block. If you want to be able to read from other text files, change your parameter name to something like `text_file` (or whatever you want to call it) and make sure to include the string when calling the function.

Comment: How would I change that so that it only showed the letters that were inside the text file?

Comment: See the code I put in my answer. Copy and paste it and run it, it should work for you. Then go back and check how it differs from your original code. That should give some insights into why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck in learning :)

Comment: I was wondering if there's a ways of only showing the letters that were in the text file and not showing the whole alphabet

Comment: Sure there is. But it will require you to approach the problem in a different way. You can loop through the contents of the file with a for loop (which iterates over each _line_ of the file, and then do a for loop over each line, which iterates over each _character_ of that line. Add each character you find to a dictionary of found letters and increment the number of times it was found. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the syntax because this problem is the exact same as one I solved while I was learning, too and it was really helpful to struggle through it.

Answer (score -1):

In your function you can't have example.txt as a parameter name.

The following code only traverses through the letters of the text and not the whole alphabet set. I am using a dict to store the frequency of letters. `isalpha` is used so that we just put alphabets in the dictionary.

```
import collections
import string

def count_letters(textfile, case_sensitive=False):
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
        original_text = f.read()
        if case_sensitive:

            text = original_text
        else:

            text = original_text.lower()

        p = dict()

        for i in text:
            if i in p.keys():
                p[i] += 1
            elif i.isalpha():
                p[i] = 1;

        keys = p.keys()

        for k in keys:
            print str(k) + " " + str(p[k])


count_letters("example.txt")
```

Comment: example.txt is the file name that contains `Hi there`

Comment: Yes but you can't pass it as a parameter. What you can do is pass the name of the file as String. And then use it inside the function.

Comment: I've used the example shown in the answer above and it works but it goes through all the alphabet where I only want the letters in the text file to be shown

Comment: Its because of the code that you have written. You are traversing through the whole alphabet set. Moreover, The answer given above is almost same as mine. Just he has given you the corrected code and I have not. I expected you to correct your mistake yourself once it is pointed.

Comment: I'm using the code above and I was wondering if you knew a way of not displaying the whole alphabet set

Comment: @smitthy : I have updated my answer. Do let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @smitthy : Did it work?

Comment: Why was it downvoted?